# Will JDK 8 will integrate with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, java-8

Will JDK 8 will integrate with Eclipse?

I want to integrate JDK8 with Eclipse 3.8 in order to run `hadoop`- map reduce program.

Comment: Proper Java 8 support is only in Eclipse 4.4 onwards (Eclipse Luna or Mars)

Comment: @greg-449 thank u so much for your info